# Possible to take multiple input files and not create one RDD in pyspark?

Tags: hadoop, pyspark

In Hadoop, I can point an app to a path which then the mappers will process the files individually.  I have to handle it this way because I need to parse the file name and path to match up with other files that I load directly in the mappers.

In pyspark, passing the path to SparkContext's textFile creates one RDD.  Is there any way to replicate the same Hadoop behavior in Spark / pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this resolve some of your confusions :
`sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(path)` returns a `pairRDD` (helpful link: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/ch04.html)

In short, pairRDD is more like a map (i.e. have key, value)

```
rdd = sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(path)

def func_work_on_individual_files(x):
   # x is a tuple which will receive both (key, value) for the pairRDD Row Elements passed. key -> file path, value -> content of a file with line seperated by '/n' (as you mentioned). To access key use x[0], to access value use x[1]. 
   # your logic to do something useful with file data, 
   # to get separate lines you can use: x[1].split('\n')
   # end function by return the values you want to return out of a file's data. 

   # I am simply returning the whole content of file 
   return x[1] 


#loop over each of the file in the pairRdd created above
file_contents = rdd.map(func_work_on_individual_files)

#this will create just one partition out of all elements in list (as you mentioned)
consolidated_contents = file_contents.repartition(1)

#Save final output - this will create just one path like Hadoop
consolidated_contents.saveAsTextFile(path)
```

Comment: Thanks!  But during that process it will no longer be a rdd but a list?  Due to size, I need to keep it as a rdd / don't want to lose it in transit.  I may change the input to get around this.

Comment: Marking as answer but handled it a little differently.  I need to pair the data with something else by index and it became too problematic as I could not find a way to keep the data from becoming a non RDD object.  I'm just using wholeTextFiles as a way to get all the file names now.  Not too fond of the solution but it'll work.  Thank you for the help!  It does help clarify some things

Comment: Till the time you dont use an action, it is still a rdd. In my example code the only action is "saveAsTextFile". All other operations are transformation i.e. does not create a list or any other definite data-structure.  I am still not clear about your use case, but if you want to tag file name with each record (each line of your data), you can return a key, value pair from "func_work_on_individual_files" and it will keep it a pairRDD. or you can de-normalize each record in multiple way , example: tag file name to each record (each line) with a delimiter and return index, record from udf.

Answer (score 0):

Pyspark provides a function for this use case:  `sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(path)`. It will read a directory of text files and produce a key-value pair, where key is the path of each file and value is the content of each file.

Comment: How would you iterate over the files?  I tried doing something like this..."files.collect().foreach(lambda file:"...
but any assignment fails.  files are an rdd of string filenames.  seems like it's possible to do in Scala-spark.

Comment: Also, I'd imagine that if I do manage to iterate over it that the outputs would be separate require different output folders?  In Hadoop it would be one output (well split by part file but can be combined into one file)

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to iterate this but noticed that this method actually returns a much different structure for an input.  textFile will return a list of lists but wholeTextFiles returns "content" with "\r" and "\n" as separators.  Really don't understand why it would be handled any differently.